# Can I persist application data via Javascript between browsers?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, persistence, local-storage

I'd like to persist a list of favorited items for all browsers on the user's machine.

Cookies are too volatile, and localStorage, while useful, does not move between browsers.

Are Flash's Local Session Objects my best bet?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, flash's local session objects are one of the ways evercookies happen - flash's own storage is shared between ALL apps that use flash on a system, and that includes browsers.

Comment: and what makes you think that users change their browser?

Comment: _"Cookies are too volatile"_ - and don't work between browsers either do they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Because Flash persists data outside the of the normal browser storage mechanism, it's the only sane way to try to persist data across a reasonable spectrum of browsers.

http://www.nuff-respec.com/technology/cross-browser-cookies-with-flash

This link explains how to set a shared object in Flash, and then retrieve it with Javascript.